# MySQL: how to sort some records in ASC and some in DESC order, based on another field's value

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a table of "tickets".
Table structure:

> - unique ID (auto-increment)
> - status (open/closed/exception)
> - priority (numeric, larger number = higher priority)
> - creation_date
> - etc...

I need to retrieve the tickets in the following order:

> - "open" tickets first, sorted by priority (highest first), then by creation_date (oldest first)
> - "closed" tickets next, sorted by creation_date (newest first)

This could be done with a UNION of two queries, but this would add a lot of complexity.

Any suggestions for accomplishing this in a single query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `union all`.  Use multiple keys in the `order by`:

```
select t.*
from t
where status in ('open', 'closed')
order by (status = 'open') desc,
         (case when status = 'open' then priority end) desc,
         (case when status = 'open' then creation_date end) asc,
         (case when status = 'closed' then creation_date end) desc
```

Comment: PERFECT.  I didn't realize CASE statements could be used in that way. Thank you for the enlightenment.